# Log4j using the error method

Tags: jsp, logging, methods, log4j

So from what I've read, you need to actually know in your code where there's an error before you can log that error?

And what about for fatal errors? How exactly am I supposed to know where a fatal error occurs and why wouldn't I just fix the code instead? 0_o

Answer (score 0):

Error handling is a big subject, but if you use try catch blocks then you can log errors. For example:

```
private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger("myLog");

public void method() {
    try {
        doStuff(m, s);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("ERROR: this is bad" );
        errorHandler(e); // send the error to where we handle all runtime errors

        // Print the stack
        StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + errors);
    }
}
```

In this case the code will continue past the catch block and not stop. It will only log. However, if a fatal error occurred then your code wouldn't work and it should *stop*.

Another thing is, in your errorHandler code you can arrange to play sounds, send emails, update monitoring systems, etc etc so you know what's going on.

Comment: I've thought about doing this, but then I'd be try catching almost every single thing then.

Comment: have a look at the Introduction here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/index.html